# *_url helpers don't work with varying subdomain levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a site with an `api` subdomain. On the same domain where the site is located, I've also got a `dev` subdomain with, you guessed it, a development version of the site.

My issue is that this dev version of the site also has an `api` subdomain (ie: `api.dev.example.com`. The routes work without issue using a regex to match the last segment of the subdomain against `api` (`/api(?:\..*)?/`), but the `*_url` helpers do not generate what I would like. Instead of spitting out `http://api.dev.example.com/somepath`, they spit out `http://dev.example.com/somepath`.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require special handling of the dev site vs the prod site. Subdomain sniffing based on requests so some such nonsense does not appeal to me.

Relevant routes.rb content:

```
constraints subdomain: /api(?:\..*)?/, format: 'json', protocol: 'http://' do
    get '/' => 'example#index'
    post '/create', to: 'example#create', as: :api_create_example
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the subdomain to the url helper:

```
fear_and_loathing_in_las_vegas_url(subdomain: 'api.dev')
```

This will generate `http://api.dev.example.com/fear_and_loathing_in_las_vegas`

Comment: How does that help? The same views are visible in dev and non-dev, so the subdomain could be either. Your solution assumes I can statically determine which it will be prior to running...